# replace null value with empty string in several columns while fetching data

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

My sql query :

```
select * from users where email = email and password=password;
```

Result  :

[image: result]

Expected Result :

[image: expected result]

**I want to replace all null values with the empty string(" ").**

Comment: I think, you need to write a wrapper that checks the values and make it empty for null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE [**COALESCE**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) or [**IFNULL**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php).

**Example:**

**Using `IFNULL`**:

```
SELECT 
 IFNULL(firstName,'') AS firstName,
 IFNULL(lastName,'') AS lastName,
 ....
FROM YOUR_TABLE.
```

**Using `COALESCE`**:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(firstName,'') AS firstName,
  COALESCE(lastName,'') AS lastName,
  ....
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

**Note:**

The main difference between the two is that `IFNULL` function takes two arguments and returns the first one if it's not NULL or the second if the first one is `NULL`.

`COALESCE` function can take two or more parameters and returns the first non-`NULL` parameter, or `NULL` if all parameters are `null`

Comment: i have 9 columns which holding the null value. if i use the above methods ,the codes go longer. Is there any alternative for that

Comment: If you want to skip this **NULL checking** in query level then you must have to do this somewhere else (e.g. Application level or client end). Another way could be updating the `Null` values with empty string in your table and later altering the columns to `NOT NULL`

Comment: If you allow `NULL` value during insertion then I think you can approach this way I mean using `COALESCE/IFNULL`